# My PhP script doesn't write on my MySql database

Tags: php, mysql

I started to learn PHP and I need your help because I'm trying to write on my MySQL database. The script seems fine (for me :D) and it doesn't give me errors. But when I submit the query the data doesn't appear inside my MySQL database. Could you help me, please?

This is my HTML/PHP code:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['message'] = '';

//connection variables

$host = '127.0.0.1';
$user = 'root';
$password = 'MyPassword';
$database= 'test';
$port= '3306';

//create mysql connection
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $password,$database,$port);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connection failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    die();
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $name = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
    $email = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    if ($mysqli->query("INSERT INTO 'contatti' ('name', 'email') VALUES ('$name','$email')") == true) {
        $_SESSION['message'] = "registration succesfull! Added $name to the database";
    } else {
        $_SESSION['message'] = "User can't be added to the database";
    }
}
?>


    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <center>
        <h1>Inputs</h1>
        <form class="form" action="welcome.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
            <div class="alert alert-error"><?= $_SESSION['message'] ?></div>
     <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Insert your name" /> <br>
     <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Insert your email"/><br>
     <input type="submit" name="submit" placeholder="Submit"/>
        </form>
        </center>
    </html>
```

This is the database:
[Table structure]
[[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezODA.png)
[Database info]
[image]

Comment: You didn't pass your database name, you can pass it like this: $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $db); after defining your database name in variable $db

Comment: Could you please include all relevant information in the question itself, rather than linking to images on another site?

Comment: @Roland Weber, he can't he isn't a high enough rank. -Andrea - You're not connecting to your database, you need the name of it in your mysqli object parameter. See Hesham's comment for more.

Comment: @c-hunter Table structure can be described in text form, regardless of rank.

Comment: @RolandWeber Regardless, stackoverflow has the feature to link images, so it's obviously the OPs choice, it actually makes it very easy to follow. If you don't like it there's a edit button under his comment, just click that and make it the way you like it :)

Comment: @HeshamAbuSaif I added the db and port but it still not working

Comment: @AndreaFerrario check my answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your query, try to change the `INSERT` query inside the if condition here:

```
 if ($mysqli->query("INSERT INTO 'contatti' ('name', 'email') VALUES ('$name','$email')") == true) {
        $_SESSION['message'] = "registration succesfull! Added $name to the database";
    } else {
        $_SESSION['message'] = "User can't be added to the database";
    }
```

To be like this:

```
  if ($mysqli->query("INSERT INTO contatti (name, email) 
             VALUES('$name', '$email')") == true) {
        $_SESSION['message'] = "registration succesfull! Added $name to the database";
    } else {
        $_SESSION['message'] = "User can't be added to the database";
    }
```

Comment: @AndreaFerrario can you tell me what is the error showing ?

Comment: Thank you! Now it's working I wrote form the beginning the script with the correct syntax and now it's working!

Comment: @AndreaFerrario glad to help

Comment: You should not use variables directly in queries. This is the rule.

Comment: @Ostin The answer is just for the question been asked for the problem in the insertion, because of the syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Please use preapared statements and bind parameters instead: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

You can also debug your mysql server response with `error_list`:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `contatti` (`name`, `email`) VALUES (?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $name, $email);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        /* ... */
    }
    else {
        $errors = $stmt->error_list;
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use prepared statements for MYSQL and PHP, if possible, at least to protect yourself from SQL injection ([SO Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)).

That said, when you read this line :

`if ($mysqli->query("INSERT INTO 'contatti' ('name', 'email') VALUES ($name,$email)") == true)`

You are concatening strings into your SQL query without quotes, and the query string look like (with $name = 'test', $email = 'test@test' :

`INSERT INTO 'contatti' ('name', 'email') VALUES (test,test@test)` : incorrect syntax

You must escape strings on SQL :

`if ($mysqli->query("INSERT INTO 'contatti' ('name', 'email') VALUES ('$name', '$email' )") == true)`

The resulting query should look like : `INSERT INTO 'contatti' ('name', 'email') VALUES ('test','test@test')`

**Edit :** please note that the table (contatti) and the fields name (name, email) are supposed to be **surrounded by backticks, not single quotes** (I cannot escape backticks in a quote), and variables $name and $email by single quotes

Comment: I changed the query and it still not working. I updated the script

Comment: In addition, make sure that your primary key in phpMyAdmin (the "id" field) has the default attribute set to "Default", not "None", otherwise you have to provide the "id" value yourself...

Comment: there isn't the Default attribute